# What is this effect used by a lot of voice actors called?

Tags: audio-recording, voice, voice-over

I am looking for a specific voice effect that I have listened to in many videos on youtube and other places. I don't know what it is called and it also does not sound natural. Here are examples -

https://vimeo.com/224179742

https://www.voices.com/actors/adasa1329#bio

https://www.voices.com/actors/ankkitarorah#bio

Do you notice the subtle 'errrrr'/crunchiness/vibration/distortion/robotic sound at the end of many words? I understand it may be difficult to understand by my explanation but hope someone recognizes it.

I would like to know if this effect has a name or something so as to search further into it or is there is a youtube tutorial somewhere that I can follow, to begin with. Any kind of pointers would help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a specific effect, it is simply the result of the V/O artist's voice plus some fairly standard dialogue mixing effects chains, including de-essing, compression and EQ. Nothing more than that.

The main component of what you are hearing is actually the voice of the V/O artist.